# How to stop these android build messages [CXX5200] ABIs [arm64-v8a,armeabi-v7a,armeabi]

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I am building my Android 34 application and getting the following warning messages for a c++ module within my application. I realise they are only warnings and i can safely ignore them, however i would like to know how to stop them appearing.

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"[CXX5200] ABIs [arm64-v8a,armeabi-v7a,armeabi] set by 'android.injected.build.abi' gradle flag contained 'armeabi' which is invalid.","sources":[{}]}
[CXX5200] ABIs [arm64-v8a,armeabi-v7a,armeabi] set by 'android.injected.build.abi' gradle flag contained 'armeabi' which is invalid.
```

I am using `agp = "8.2.0-alpha10"` and tried this in my c++ module

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdk = 26

    testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    consumerProguardFiles("consumer-rules.pro")
    ndk {
        abiFilters += listOf("arm64-v8a", "x86", "x86_64")
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            cppFlags += ""
        }
    }
}
```

which made no difference to these messages
is there any approach i can use to stop these messages?

this is the android studio version i am using

```
Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Canary 10
Build #AI-231.9011.34.2311.10366083, built on June 22, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.7+0-17.0.7b829.16-10353782 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 12.6.1
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 4096M
Cores: 12
Metal Rendering is ON
Registry:
    external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
    debugger.new.tool.window.layout=true
    ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false
    ide.experimental.ui=true
    ide.images.show.chessboard=true

Non-Bundled Plugins:
    com.github.rmehri01.onenord (0.0.6)
    com.arcticicestudio.nord.jetbrains (0.13.0)
```

Comment: Is the `+=` in your `abiFilters` line intentional? I think you meant to assign, not append.

Comment: when i remove the + i receive an error message saying a val cannot be reassigned @Botje

Comment: Because you're not supposed to invoke it like that. [See official documentation](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis).

Comment: Im using gradle kts not gradle. those official docs only show gradle examples